# integer64 to datatime conversion in R issue?

Tags: r, datetime, unix-timestamp, lubridate

Given the following `dataframe` of `integer64` unix epoch:

```
data_df <- structure(list(time_stamp = structure(c(0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396
), class = "integer64")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I want to convert it to date time (`as.POSIXct` or `anytime()`) but I get an error:

```
    data_df %>%
  dplyr::select(time_stamp) %>% 
  head(10) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(dt = anytime(time_stamp)) %>% dput()
```

Gives:

```
structure(list(time_stamp = structure(c(0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396
    ), class = "integer64"), dt = structure(c(0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396, 
    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Etc/UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

data_df %>%
  dplyr::select(time_stamp) %>% 
  head(10) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(dt = as.POSIXct(time_stamp))
```

> Error in as.POSIXct.default(time_stamp) : do not know how to convert
>   'time_stamp' to class “POSIXct”

Please advice how to deal with `integer64` epoch times.

Comment: Seems correct. What is your issue? You need to define the `origin` so the `as.POSIXct` can add your integer to that origin and hence get the date

Comment: Oh, hold on. You get different error... I run your last piece of code and I got that: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: 'origin' must be supplied.`

Comment: These look like nano-seconds. This seems to give a somewhat reasonable date, but I don't know if it is correct: `as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC") + data_df$time_stamp / 1e9`. (There is a loss of precision during the division. If that is important you need to use high-precision numbers instead of floats.)

Comment: So each time I need to figure out by what constant to divide the number and set origin to be 1970-01-01? @Sotos

Comment: So each time I need to figure out by what constant to divide the number and set origin to be 1970-01-01? @Roland

Comment: You shouldn't need to figure out. You should know from the specifications of the system that created these times.

Comment: Or to use a function and an indicator if it's nano/milli/micro seconds. We get absolutely different timestamps some are large like you've seen and some are shorter.

Comment: If you know the expected date range, it isn't difficult to detect the unit automatically. Write a small function.

Comment: I am coming to this late but a) this has nothing to with `anytime` which you do not use but it b) would have something to do with `nanotime` which helps you deal with nano-second resolution timestamps in `integer64`.  I use those all the time from `data.table`.  YMMV with `dplyr` and `tibble`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pardon the direct language, but your question makes no sense.  Taking the first element of your dataset: `0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282505613660396`.  That is simply not representable in *any* of the datatypes you listed.  Including `integer64`.  Full stop.

Now, it so happens that my [`nanotime`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=nanotime) package does this *at the best available resolution* which is nanoseconds represented in 64-integers.  And 64 bit integers allow for nanosecond increments since the epoch, at about 19 digits precision.  Not the 100+ digits you demanded.  No (small memory) variable can.

As for `nanotime`, the `example()` shows some uses, including parsing:

```
R> library(nanotime)
R> example(nanotime)

nanotmR> x <- nanotime("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000001+00:00")

nanotmR> print(x)
[1] "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000001+00:00"

nanotmR> x <- x + 1

nanotmR> print(x)
[1] "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000002+00:00"

nanotmR> format(x)
[1] "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000002+00:00"

nanotmR> x <- x + 10

nanotmR> print(x)
[1] "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000012+00:00"

nanotmR> format(x)
[1] "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000012+00:00"

nanotmR> format(nanotime(Sys.time()) + 1:3)  # three elements each 1 ns apart
[1] "2019-03-10T20:06:53.534292001+00:00" "2019-03-10T20:06:53.534292002+00:00" 
[3] "2019-03-10T20:06:53.534292003+00:00"
R>
```

Best of all, `data.table` has support for the `integer64` type of the `bit64` packages that is used here.  Building on the example:

```
R> library(data.table)
data.table 1.12.0  Latest news: r-datatable.com
R> dt <- data.table(ns = nanotime(Sys.time()) + 1:3)
R> dt[]
                                    ns
1: 2019-03-10T20:08:48.165136001+00:00
2: 2019-03-10T20:08:48.165136002+00:00
3: 2019-03-10T20:08:48.165136003+00:00
R> dt[, pt := as.POSIXct(ns)]
R> dt[]
                                    ns                         pt
1: 2019-03-10T20:08:48.165136001+00:00 2019-03-10 15:08:48.165136
2: 2019-03-10T20:08:48.165136002+00:00 2019-03-10 15:08:48.165136
3: 2019-03-10T20:08:48.165136003+00:00 2019-03-10 15:08:48.165136
R>
```

I use this dual representation of nanosecond granularity with POSIXct representation for R use including plotting all day long.  (Note that there is a formatting mishap which shows the `nanotime` / `integer64` column in UTC but the underlying representation is sound and correct as the `pt` conversion to `POSIXct` shows.  It is currently just after 3pm in my timezone.)

Comment: Unable to aggregate in zoo when time is nanotime structure.  dput(head(sampler,10))
structure(c(" 134775", " 142110", "  79900", "  73893", "  91030", 
" 113602", " 129546", " 134999", " 131465", " 136492"), index = new("nanotime", 
    .S3Class = "integer64", structure(c(2.69467041777383e-201, 
2.69467041777383e-201, 2.69467041783873e-201, 2.69467042886863e-201, 
2.69467042955947e-201, 2.69467043387697e-201, 2.69467043615511e-201, 
2.69467043615511e-201, 2.69467045797641e-201, 2.69467045797641e-201
), class = "integer64")), class = "zoo")

Comment: Yes. `zoo` is doumented to work only on ordered observations of the `Date` or `POSIXct` type.  Use `data.table` with `nanotime`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is descriptive in this case. `as.POSIXct` does not handle integer64. Here are a few simple commands that indicate as such

```
library(bit64)

i <- 1
i64 <- as.integer64(i)

as.POSIXct(i, tz='UTC', origin='1970-01-01')

## You will get an error here
as.POSIXct(i64, tz='UTC', origin='1970-01-01')
```

If you can live with the lower precision (got some time before 2038), you can convert to integer.